# PHP Slim3 on HostGator with custom htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to deploy a `Slim` PHP framework on a HostGator account.

My project source looks like this:

```
project/
├── .htaccess
├── src/
│   ├── classes/
│   ├── vendor/
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── routes.php
│   ├── settings.php
│   └── index.php
└── public/
    ├── index.php
    └── .htaccess
```

And is deployed identically, where the `project` folder is the highest level folder on my HostGator account, where things like `public_html` and other things are.

Following the [tutorial](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) I added an `htaccess` into `public` as such (word for word)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And also somewhere along the way I added this to the root `htaccess` file (which also includes a setting to use PHP7, and that works..)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access the site with these new `htaccess` files I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Obviously my htaccess(s) are wrong, I just don't know what is wrong. I suppose what is supposed to happen is any request should be sent to `public/index.php` first and `Slim` and myself will handle the routing.

---

public/index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../src/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

// require custom classesw
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    require ("../src/classes/" . $classname . ".php");
});

session_start();

$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['logger'] = function($c) {
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('my_logger');
    $file_handler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler("../src/logs/app.log");
    $logger->pushHandler($file_handler);
    return $logger;
};



$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello");
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your host has `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Yes   http://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-and-mod_speling

Comment: Did you app works locally?, can you post the code of your `index.php` file in your `public` folder?

Comment: I have added it to the question , and I have no local test

Comment: So you never test your app or see it working...then my first assumption is that your code is not working, and that your problem is not related to your `.htaccess`

Comment: Well it is but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Moved `public` to `public_html`

main `htaccess` file reverted to whatever is normal (aka nothing).

public `htaccess` file

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`